# Android Data Binding pass arguments to onClick method

Tags: java, android, xml, data-binding

Is it possible to pass custom arguments to `onClick` method using the Data Binding Library? I have my layout xml file where I need to use the onClickListener:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout ...>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.productivity.tiktak.ui.tracker.viewModel.CategoryViewModel"/>
        <variable
            name="callback"
            type="com.productivity.tiktak.ui.tracker.TrackerAdapter"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:onClick="@{callback.onCategoryClick(viewModel)}"
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <!-- ... Some stuff -->

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

and I a have my click handler code here:

```
public void onCategoryClick(View view, CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel)
{
    //handler code...
}
```

**Is it possible to pass my CategoryViewModel object from xml to click handler?**

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You can use a lambda expressions and pass the view in as a parameter.

```
 android:onClick="@{() -> callback.onCategoryClick(viewModel)}"
```

If you need the view, you can pass that as well with:

```
 android:onClick="@{(view) -> callback.onCategoryClick(view, viewModel)}"
```

Comment: is there another way to do this as the lambda is not compiling?

Comment: please add more details

Comment: note: Here v is the view of the root just like context (keyword available in xml), not the current clicked view

Comment: I used the same but does not enter click method.

Comment: How do I pass other views along with this one to the same function?

Comment: kindly checkout mention link for onClick normal and custom click https://github.com/rakeshrajput379/ClickEventMVVM

Answer (score 25):

#### Multiple Ways:

#### Solution 1 (When you have Presenter)

You have a presenter or handler class like below

```
public class Presenter {
    public void onSaveClick(View view, Task task){}
}
```

Now take variable of type `Presenter` in your layout. and set click like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="task" type="com.android.example.Task" />
        <variable name="presenter" type="com.android.example.Presenter" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        <Button 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:onClick="@{(view) -> presenter.onSaveClick(view, task)}"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

You can add any more arguments in this.

Please note that, you have to set these data variables in the `onCreate()` method. Like below

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding.setTask(task);
binding.setPresenter(presenter);
```

#### Solution 2 (When you don't have Presenter)

Create a variable type of your Activity / Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="task" type="com.android.example.Task" />
        <variable name="activity" type="com.example.MainActivity" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        <Button 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:onClick="@{(view) -> activity.onSaveClick(view, task)}"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and make method in your activity which you want to call from binding layout. and **don't forget to call** `setActivity(YourActivity.this)` from Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onSaveClick(View view, Task task) {
        System.out.println("MainActivity.onSaveClick");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setActivity(this);
        binding.setTask(task);
    }
}
```

Further reading **[Android DataBinding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#java)**

There are many other ways to set click, check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894776/6891563)

Comment: Hi Khemraj, Is that possible to open new activity with android.onClick? Can you show me how since following with Android document I cant able to implement.

Comment: @SukeshSaxena Can you please put a new question and give me its link. I can't explain here, because this question is not related to that.