# Get values other views when onClick. DataBinding

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I have xml with android data binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable name="presenter" type="com.myapp.presentation.presenter.CreateUserPresenter"/>
    </data>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/firstNameInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:hint="@string/first_name" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/secondNameInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:hint="@string/second_name" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/create"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> presenter.createUser()}" />    
            </LinearLayout>    
</layout>
```

and `CreateUserPresenter.class`:

```
public class CreateUserPresenter {

    public CreateUserPresenter () {}

    public void createUser(String firstName, String lastName) {

    }
}
```

How to pass the input (`firstNameInput` and `secondNameInput`) values in the method `createUser()` on click button?

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> presenter.createUser()}"
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37105213/1790537

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a best practice to follow MVVM when you are working with DataBinding, however with your code also you can pass string values.

Try with this

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> presenter.createUser(firstNameInput.getEditText().getText().toString(),secondNameInput.getEditText().getText().toString())}"
```