# Getting text from EditText wigdet by using DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-viewbinding

I am using data binding in my project. I understand binding data to certain model, but now i want to call an implicit intent to open google maps in this layout. Code on which i would call implicit intent is located within LinearLayout. I am not sure how to implement this, can someone give me any idea... I wanted to use ViewBinding on this one, but i am not sure if that is even possible. Some help, please? I din't mention that i am using Java.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="secondarySpinnerAdapter"
            type="android.widget.ArrayAdapter" />
        <variable
            name="secondaryClickHandler"
            type="mypackagename.MainActivity.MainActivityClickHandlers" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/store_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="8">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_store_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_default"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:hint="@string/et_store_search_hint"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_default" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_store_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_default"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_default"
                android:onClick="@{secondaryClickHandler::onSearchStoreClicked}"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvShopItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/store_search"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the value to function inside viewmodel.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_store_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_default"
    android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.onSearchStoreClicked(et_store_search.getText().toString())}"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />
```

View Model Function :

```
fun onSearchStoreClicked(search: String) {
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "searchText $search");
}
```

Comment: if for someone this is not working try using `etStoreSearch` instead of `et_store_search` in the `android:onClick` layout expression. Because the binding class converts IDs to camel case as mentioned in the docs here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#view_references

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this question for the above solution:

> [Android Data Binding pass arguments to onClick method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105066/android-data-binding-pass-arguments-to-onclick-method)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after all. XML code isn't touched after all. All I needed to do was this

```
public void onSearchStoreClicked(View view) {
            Intent intent =
                    new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + activityMainBinding
                                    .secondaryLayout
                                    .etStoreSearch.getText().toString()));

            if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cant handle this intent!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If another post helped you can upvote, but it is not needed to add noise to your self-answer.