# How to get Position & View information through onclick Binding Adapter implemented with ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, android-recyclerview

I want to use Data Binding Library & ViewModel

1. to identify position of clicked item in List.
2. To know on which view the click happened so that I can trigger different Intent.

Here is my XML file (Currently onclick is on RelativeLayout)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <variable name="orgmembvm" 
   type="com.support.android.designlibdemo.include.OrgMemb" />
    <variable name="orgmembhandlers" 
  type="com.support.android.designlibdemo.View.MyOrgMembHandlers"/>
 </data>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/org_memb_rec"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="@{orgmembhandlers::onClickOpenEditRec}"
    android:padding="8dp">
   //Inner Child element
  </RelativeLayout>
```

BindViewHolder of Adaptor

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrgMembViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
    holder.mBinding.setOrgmembvm(orgMembArrayList.get(position));
    holder.mBinding.setOrgmembhandlers(new MyOrgMembHandlers());
    holder.mBinding.executePendingBindings();
 }
```

Code in Activity Class for getting viewModel attached to Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
......
......
userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OrgMembViewModel.class);
userModel.getAllLive().observe(this, orgMembList -> {
mAdapter.updateorgmemblist(orgMembList);
    });
  }
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1. Take position variable in layout

```
<variable
    name="position"
    type="int"/>
```

#### 2. set position from adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrgMembViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mBinding.setPosition(position);
}
```

#### 3. Put int position in `onClickOpenEditRec` param

```
public class MyOrgMembHandler {
    public void onClickOpenEditRec(int position) {

    }
}
```

#### 4. Pass position from layout

```
android:onClick="@{()->orgmembhandlers.onClickOpenEditRec(position)}"
```

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894776/6891563) to see ways of setting click in data binding.

Comment: Thanx Khemraj. This helps a lot.

Comment: Glad to help you bro.

Comment: Khemraj can you help me on my new post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057195/data-downloading-through-mvvm-model