# How to attach custom event through data binding?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-spinner, android-databinding

***Note:*** also review the edited code at the bottom for further development.

How can we attach / assign an event to spinner using data binding, specifically by listener bindings.
Here is an [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html) regarding the usage of data binding. So, I was trying the code and failed to assign an event.

on **Android Studio 3.2.1**

***activity_parents_reg.xml***

```
    <data>
        <import type="java.util.ArrayList" />
        <variable name="handlers"
            type="com.example.myUser.myapplication.custom.MyHandlers"
        />
        <variable
            name="cities"
            type="ArrayList&lt;String>"
        />
    <data>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dd_city"
        android:entries="@{cities}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> handlers.onClickFriend()}"
        style="@style/dropdown"
    />
```

***MyHandlers.java***

```
   public class MyHandlers {
        public void onClickFriend(View view) {}
   }
```

***ParentsReg.java***

```
    //  Data binding
        ActivityParentsRegBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_parents_reg);
        binding.setCities(ConstData.getCitiesList());
        binding.setHandlers(new MyHandlers());
```

Here is the error receiving on compilation:

```
    Found data binding errors.

    ****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method onClickFriend() in class 
    com.example.myUser.myapplication.custom.MyHandlers 
    file:/home/myUser/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/
    res/layout/activity_parents_reg.xml loc:103:37 - 103:60 
    ****\ data binding error ****
```

---

***Edited:***

Now, After observing and experimenting. I got the another perspective of my code that ensures syntax is fine.

Actually the spinner is making problem. Maybe it needs an adapter to set the events.

Here it is, working around to `Button` having little bit changes to code as well:

```
    // Activity layout changes.
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reg_submit"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="@{(view) -> handlers.onClickFriend(view)}"
        style="@style/btn_secondary"
    />
```

---

```
    // MyHandlers class changes.
    public class MyHandlers {

        private Context _context;

        public MyHandlers(Context context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void onClickFriend(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(_context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

---

```
    // Activity class changes.
    binding.setHandlers(new MyHandlers(context));
```

Still stuck with spinner.

Hopefully I will get the answer.

Comment: I think the error message is clear. What is it you don't understand about "cannot find method onClickFriend() in class com.example.myUser.myapplication.custom.MyHandlers"?

Comment: @m0skit0 Indeed, you are right. But what is the reason why it failed to find that method. its same as in official documentation. But still no clue

Comment: @ForWebTech Here is explanation of ways for setting click, you should check. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894776/6891563, if you are still unable to resolve you can comment again.